# Efficient method for matching data in multiple csv files

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, pandas

Here is a snippet of my code:

```
for i,r1 in enumerate(Solution.values):
    h1=ProjectedRevenue.index[i]
    District_ID,Instrument_ID,Buy_or_not,Revenue=r1
    listSol=[]
    listSol.append(h1)
    listSol.append(list(r1)[0])
    listSol.append(list(r1)[1])
    for j,r2 in enumerate(ProjectedRevenue.values):
        h2=ProjectedRevenue.index[j]
        if h2 == listSol[0]:
            District_ID,Instrument_ID,Annual_Projected_Revenue= r2
            listPR=list(r2)
            if listSol[1] == listPR[1] & listSol[2] == listPR[2]:
                if(listPR[2]>0):
                    #do stuff
                    continue
                else:
                    #do stuff
                    continue
```

I need some help regarding this code. I'm new to python, and I have to search and compare data entries from multiple .csv files. I have seen itertuples but it is not able to recognise the function. So I just made this to search and perform operations via pandas but this has a complexity of $O(n^2)$ and is very slow. Any help regarding this?

**EDIT**: So I am using pandas and numpy in the code to manipulate data. And to make it more clear, I need to do a search such that elements of the same index coloumns in two different files are same. Consider the example below:

Solution.csv:

```
Hospital_ID,District_ID,Instrument_ID
1,4,6
2,5,4
7,8,5
```

ProjectedRevenue.csv:

```
Hospital_ID,District_ID,Instrument_ID
9,3,5
7,8,5
1,2,6
```

So here the common entry is 7,8,5 in the two files.I want to know the fastest way to search and match them.

**UPDATE**: The previous question was about a syntax error which is resolved.

Comment: I know the previous bug was silly. Can you please remove your downvote? That does not attract quality answers.

Comment: can you post sample CSVs and desired / expected data set / CSV?

Comment: is [that](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38675126/5741205) what you want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this vectorized pandas approach:

```
In [22]: fn1 = r'D:\temp\.data\38673647\Solution.csv'

In [23]: fn2 = r'D:\temp\.data\38673647\ProjectedRevenue.csv'

In [24]: df1 = pd.read_csv(fn1)

In [25]: df2 = pd.read_csv(fn2)

In [26]: df1
Out[26]:
   Hospital_ID  District_ID  Instrument_ID
0            1            4              6
1            2            5              4
2            7            8              5

In [27]: df2
Out[27]:
   Hospital_ID  District_ID  Instrument_ID
0            9            3              5
1            7            8              5
2            1            2              6

In [28]: pd.merge(df1, df2, on=df1.columns.tolist())
Out[28]:
   Hospital_ID  District_ID  Instrument_ID
0            7            8              5
```

Comment: I'll try this for sure. I'll wait for other answers before I accept yours.

Comment: @Rohinb97, actually it should be __much__ faster compared to nested loop approach, especially on bigger files

Comment: My data set wasn't big enough. I can see the effect. Thanks!

Comment: I wanted to wait for other answers but since there aren't any so you can get those extra rep

Answer (score 0):

use `:` at the end of `if` check.

```
if h2 == listSol[0]:
```

Comment: This was so dumb of me. I'll correct that. Thank you.

Comment: Anything regarding the second part?

Comment: Use pandas module for second part